# NSUnicodeStringEncoding prepends FFFE to every string

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to append a string to a file by encoding it as `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` first. I'm doing this:

```
NSData *data = [@"data" dataUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
NSFileHandle *output = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:@"file"];
[output seekToEndOfFile];
[output writeData:data];
```

If I do this a number of times and then take a look at the file I notice that every string added has FFFE prepended to it. But when I switch from `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` to `NSUTF8StringEncoding` this prefix goes away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called a byte-order marker, and is put there because `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` doesn't specify whether the characters are stored in big or little endian order.

To prevent `0xFFFE` or `0xFEFF` from appearing at the beginning of a string, use one of `NSUTF16BigEndianStringEncoding`, `NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding`, `NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding`, or `NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding`, depending on your specific needs. (For reference: Intel and ARM processors as used by Apple are little endian.)